# How to pass parameters to script file under shopify using php?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, script-tag

I want to pass parameters to script.js file that is included in the script_tags.json file of shopify.
I have mentioned below the code to add script file in script_tags.json file.

```
$script_array = array(
        'script_tag' => array(
            'event' => 'onload', 
            'src' => 'https://www.softwareprive.com/shopifyapps/ngdesk/js/script.js'
        ) 
);

$scriptTag = shopify_call($token, $shop, "/admin/api/2019-10/script_tags.json", $script_array, 'POST');
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass parameters to scripts. They execute after the DOM has loaded. So your script code can access data that was prepared for your script to use. That would mean providing some Liquid and/or other theme code. Otherwise, you are left with doing scripting by introspection of the DOM and hoping you sniff out the gold you are looking for.